# Trying to make an array of objects, but getting back an array with empty objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm new to javascript and there's a problem I'm not all able to solve.
I have one array of objects, which contains 2 attributes. I want to connect the attributes, one of which will be a key and the other will be a value.

this is what I have:

```
[{"prefer":"code_html","rating":"5"},{"prefer":"code_css","rating":"3"}]
```

This is what I want to get:

```
[
  {
    "code_html": "5"
  },
  {
    "code_css": "3"
  }
]
```

I run this function:

```js
const array = [{"prefer":"code_html","rating":"5"},{"prefer":"code_css","rating":"3"}]

const result = array.map(({prefer, rating}) => ({[prefer]: rating}));

console.log(result);
```

But I can not understand why it does not work for me.
This is the print I get, I do not understand what is wrong

```
[{},{},{}]
```

I use this code in nodeJs, maybe that's why I have a problem:

```
exports.addUserKmeansMatchVer2 = (req, res) => {
  
  console.log("addUserKmeansMatch function filter:");
  arr = [];
  if(req.query.filterArray)
  {
    arr = [...req.query.filterArray];
    console.log("line 256" + typeof(req.query.filterArray));
    //this is print line 256object
    console.log("line 257" +arr); 
//this is works prints: line 257{"prefer":"sport_swimming","rating":"3"},{"prefer":"code_html","rating":"5"},{"prefer":"code_css","rating":"3"}
    console.log("line 258" + req.query.filterArray);
    //print exactly the same as line 257 
  }

  let onlyPreferencesAllow = [];
  arr.forEach(({prefer,rating}) => onlyPreferencesAllow.push({[prefer]: rating}));
  console.log("line 262" + JSON.stringify(onlyPreferencesAllow));
//this is NOT work prints: line 262[{},{},{}] 


        db.doc(`/match/${req.user.handle}`)
          .set("testing")
          .then(() => {
            return res.json({ message: "Details added successfully" });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
          });
      }
    })
  })
};
```

I noticed that in line 257 it prints for me without the parentheses of the array without [], but in line 262 it prints with the parentheses [], I do not quite understand it

I thought of something I forgot to mention,

I get the req.query.filterArray, through the params.
Here's how I do it:

```
export const makeMatchVer2 = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
  axios
    .get('/kmeansFilter', {
      params: {
        filterArray: data
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: MAKE_MATCH,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: MAKE_MATCH,
        payload: []
      });
    });
};
```

the data itself is an array, maybe here i do the mistake

Comment: can you print value of `req.query.filterArray` on the first line of if?

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof(req.query.filterArray))` if it prints `string` then you need to parse it to js object using JSON.parse.

Comment: @Molda Thanks for the help, I added a typeof print like you told me, it prints an object to me.

Comment: Then just add a console.log to the forEach loop to see the values `arr.forEach(function({prefer,rating}){ onlyPreferencesAllow.push({[prefer]: rating}); console.log(prefer,rating); });` Or maybe just `console.log(arr[0]);` which should print just the first object. Also this `console.log("line 262" + onlyPreferencesAllow);` without stringifying

Comment: @Molda Thank you very much for your help, I tried to print the first element: console.log(arr[0]), it works, brought me the first element.

Comment: @Molda When I try to print in foreach, it gives me for each element , undefined

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:
When I send an array in params to api, I need to use JSON.stringify.

```
export const makeMatchVer2 = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
  axios
    .get('/kmeansFilter', {
      params: {
        filterArray: JSON.stringify(data)
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: MAKE_MATCH,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: MAKE_MATCH,
        payload: []
      });
    });
};
```

And when I get the answer in nodeJS, I have to use JSON.parse

```
exports.addUserKmeansMatchVer2 = (req, res) => {
  
  console.log("addUserKmeansMatch function filter:");
  arr = [];
  if(req.query.filterArray)
  {
    arr = JSON.parse(req.query.filterArray);
  }

  let onlyPreferencesAllow = [];
  arr.forEach(({prefer,rating}) => onlyPreferencesAllow.push({[prefer]: rating}));
  console.log("line 262" + JSON.stringify(onlyPreferencesAllow));


        db.doc(`/match/${req.user.handle}`)
          .set("testing")
          .then(() => {
            return res.json({ message: "Details added successfully" });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
          });
      }
    })
  })
};
```